# javascript display image on screen with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a beginner in javascript and I stumbled upon this problem. 
This is a part of markup from site i'm working on:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="target">
                    <div id="bgDiv">
                        <img src ="someurl">
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

It's a part of a simple bootstrap layout.  What i want to do is to animate the #target div so that the image fills the whole browser screen on mouseover , preferably using pure javascript. If I do it with this function:

```
 function(){
    var target = document.getElementById('target');
    function FullScreen {
          target.style.cssText ='position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;z-index:999'
          document.body.appendChild(target);};
    target.addEventListener('mouseover', FullScreen)};
```

It does the job of displaying the image covering whole browser window, but I'm cluless how to make the "fill" animation. I tried experimenting with transitions, but i think since i change the 'position' property and append the element to body it does not work. 
I would be grateful for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Yes, I understand I could use the transition styles, and pure css, although the main problem is that the #target div is positioned inside the "col-lg-12" and "row" div's, and thats why positioning it :absolute doesnt do the trick. Hence my solution was appending the #target div on 'mouseover', straight to document.body element. But when i do this the transitions don't seem to work.

Comment: Try my solution. By increasing the size of the image when the event is fired the wrapped div also will begin to grow. As you can see i give the image an size relative to the screen and not to the parent div. It should work =)

Comment: Thanks for your responses, combining your solutions with appropriate positioning I managed to achive the desired effect, thank you!

Comment: No problem mate. Can you maybe mark my answer as the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Portal_Zii already mentioned, you can easy create animations without javascript using **CSS3 properties** only like:

- [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/transition)
- [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

With this knowledge its quiet simple to implement an hybrid solution with CSS3 **transition** property, the [onmouseenter](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseenter.asp) and [onmouseleave](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseleave.asp) event.
Try to run the Code and **re-size** the window.

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var myImg = document.getElementById("myImg");

myDiv.onmouseleave = shrinkImage;
myDiv.onmouseenter = growImage;

function shrinkImage() {
  myImg.style.width = 50 + "px";
  myImg.style.height = 50 + "px";
}

function growImage() {
  myImg.style.width = window.innerWidth + "px";
  myImg.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <img id="myImg" src="data:image/gif;base64,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"
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is add **transition styles** in your css:

```
#target {
      -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
      transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
      }
```

Additionally you could accomplish this in **just using css** no?

```
#target {
    DEFAULT:STYLES;
        -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
          -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
          transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
          }

    #target:hover {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        z-index:999;
            -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
              -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
              -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
              transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can describe all of the target's element properties in the class 'over' of css and describe an animation through transition on properties of position of your element. Then when you this class 'over' to element with id=target.

```
 function FullScreen {
      target.style.classList.add('over')};
```